# Position sticky with parent padding-top

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying to make something work with `position: sticky;` but I get some strange behaviour.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.parent--ok {
  background-color: green;
}

.parent--nok {
  background-color:red;
}


.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent parent--ok">
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 2</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 3</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 4</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
</div>

<div class="parent parent--nok">
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 2</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
</div>
```

I made a pen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzJENe so you can see what I mean.

I have a parent element that has a `padding-top: 25px;`, in there I have an undefined number of div pairs consisting of a header and a content. I want the headers to be sticky but with respect of the 25px padding of the parent. So I added `top: 25px;` to them. String thing is that this works as long as I have enough pairs in my parent to have an overflow. If I don't have an overflow my headers get an extra 25px spacing above, which I don't want.

this is how it looks for me:
[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: This was tested in chrome.

Comment: I don’t see why you would call that an “extra” spacing, when it happens to be exactly the amount you specified …? Your actual question rather seems to be, “I want to apply _different_ styling to elements based on whether or not their parent’s content is overflowing” …? Well that is not something CSS can handle on its own, you would need JavaScript to determine that.

Comment: But shouldn't it add the "extra spacing" to both scenario's then?

Comment: Both “Sticky” and “Sticky2” show at the exact same level in both versions of your codepen example (btw: code relevant to your question belongs directly into it, not just dumped on external sites; [mcve]), so I have no clue what you are referring to now …?

Comment: I added the snippet here as well now, thanks. If I open it in chrome is shows different on the red and green parents. In firefox they look the same

Comment: This looks and behaves exactly the same for me, in a current Firefox and current Chrome.

Comment: I have also added a screenshot now, my firefox and chrome versions are also up to date and I'm running a mac with Sierra

Comment: Nope, on my side, Chrome and Firefox does not behave the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sticky is a bit tricky, just because it is an hybrid in between fixed and relative positioned. Using top different from a 0 value for a sticky element may lead to strange behavior. I guess this is what you experienced in Chrome.

More over, you have different behavior with different browsers (or not)...
I would go for an additional container (in the sample, named `.holder` to preserve this padding-top of 25px.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent parent--ok">
    <div class="holder">
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 2</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 3</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 4</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="parent parent--nok">
    <div class="holder">
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky 2</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lectus risus, volutpat auctor mi mollis vitae. Nullam eget scelerisque odio. Cras enim ante, cursus quis feugiat id, maximus sed nibh.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.holder{
 height: 100%;
 overflow: scroll; 
}

.parent--ok {
  background-color: green;
}

.parent--nok {
  background-color:red;
}


.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

This is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/piiantom/hkdq2b6c/)